# Android UI test slicing and parallelization on Azure Devops?

Tags: android, azure-devops, integration-testing

I run Android tests on ADO on multiple emulators, each running a section of tests. But how can I get ADO itself to run a slice of tests on different ADO VMs and share the results when done?

EDIT: It seems I'm looking for how to do "distributed sharding" from [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/test_infra/tradefed/architecture/advanced/sharding).

Answer (score 0):

I donot know much about android. But i think parallel jobs in azure devops might do this task.

You can define your jobs run in parallel in below syntax. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-any-test-runner?view=azure-devops) for more information

```
jobs:
- job: ParallelTesting
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
```

If your pipeline is defined in classic view. You can refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops) to add a job to execute your test in multi-agent.

You must know that to run jobs in parallel,you must have sufficient parallel jobs. You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops) to know more information and acquire additional parallel jobs